# Squeezing pandas DataFrame to have non-null values and modify column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have the following sample DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tom': [2, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'Ron': [np.nan, 5, np.nan],
                   'Jim': [np.nan, np.nan, 6],
                   'Mat': [7, np.nan, np.nan],}, 
                   index=['Min', 'Max', 'Avg'])
```

that looks like this where **each row have only one non-null value**

```
    Tom Ron Jim Mat
Min 2.0 NaN NaN 7.0
Max NaN 5.0 NaN NaN
Avg NaN NaN 6.0 NaN
```

---

**Desired Outcome**

For each column, I want to have the non-null value and then **append the index of the corresponding non-null value to the name of the column**. So the final result should look like this

```
    Tom_Min Ron_Max Jim_Avg Mat_Min
0     2.0    5.0      6.0    7.0
```

---

**My attempt**

Using list comprehensions: Find the non-null value, and append the corresponding index to the column name and then create a new DataFrame

```
values = [df[col][~pd.isna(df[col])].values[0] for col in df.columns]

# [2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]

new_cols = [col + '_{}'.format(df[col][~pd.isna(df[col])].index[0]) for col in df.columns]

# ['Tom_Min', 'Ron_Max', 'Jim_Avg', 'Mat_Min']

df_new = pd.DataFrame([values], columns=new_cols)
```

**My question**

Is there some in-built functionality in pandas which can do this without using for loops and list comprehensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one non missing value is possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with convert `Series` to `DataFrame` and then `flatten MultiIndex`, for correct order is used [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T.swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).reindex(df.columns, level=0, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   Tom_Min  Ron_Max  Jim_Avg  Mat_Min
0      2.0      5.0      6.0      7.0
```

Comment: I tried `swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)` and that gives the same output as `swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Sheldore - hmmm, not idea... Maybe bug.

Comment: Or may be because we have only two things to swap so the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = df.T.stack()
s.index = s.index.map('_'.join)
df = s.to_frame().T
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   Tom_Min  Ron_Max  Jim_Avg  Mat_Min
0      2.0      5.0      6.0      7.0
```